# Equal height rows of articles on responsive design

Tags: javascript, ios, css, responsive-design, screen-rotation

I am trying to use https://github.com/Sam152/Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows java script plugin to achieve equal row heights on my article rows of responsive grid on http://www.snapchamp.com. The plug-in is rendering some pages ok but in some cases it's messing the margins between element like below:

[image: Article or grid elements are no longer evenly spaced]

Plugin fails when I zoom the browser window and also when I turn the orientation of ipad or mobile devices. In mobile even with single element grid the margin go messy.

So my question are:

1) Is there a better js plug-in that achieves better results?like http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/ or something else that you used in past.

2) What is order of page css rendering and javascript execution? What can be reason for such grid margin issues?

3) I tried searching for zoom events on browser and answers were almost 3-5 years old. Wonder if we have any new event that notifies javascript of zoom event on browser.

Comment: On chrome I did not have the issue you show rather where the tags were long enough to increase vertical height on the row, the plugin did not increase all of the container's respective heights. I can think of a few simple ways in js/jQuery to handle keeping all containers the same height, but without the fancy animation, if you're interested in that route.

Comment: The plugin is increasing height of rows but not sure was'up with margins. The issue was so bad that I immediately rolled back stuff on site and screen shot is from my dev server. I tried debugging the code and it seems js is doing what it was suppose to do but somehow rendering  engine is not reapplying margins after heights are changed. It will be interesting to know if browser reapply css after js changes or what exactly is order of rendering engine.. 

I am open for all solution that don't require me to add any additional css tags or break responsive design on site and works on all devices.

Comment: May help if you can provide a link to the site in the dev environment so we can see what is going on in your exact implementation. Screen shot doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Dev env is not accessible outside as internet service provider does  not allow outside traffic inside (I had issues accessing security camera feeds from outside network). Pls let me know when you would like to look into this and I will see if we could boot up another azure instance with prod image, just for test. Please let me know when will be a good time probably over weekend..

Comment: I put together a simple js/jQuery solution that should help. Going forward, generally, I put my dev environments on a separate vhost on the production server so that all the same server configurations are in play and I have the capability to share the dev environment with the client for review remotely (I only work remote). A simple http auth u/p can keep unwanted viewers out (including Search Engines). Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

I put together this simple bit of js/jQuery for you to perhaps use as a solution.
The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lekspbsv/).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //Find max height:

    var maxH = 0;

    var containers = jQuery("div.container");
    var i = 0;

    containers.each(function() {
        var h = jQuery(this).height();
        if(h > maxH)
            maxH = h;

        i += 1;
        if(i == containers.length)
            updateContainerHeight();
    });

    function updateContainerHeight()
    {
        if(typeof maxH == 'undefined' || typeof maxH == 'null')
            return;

        containers.css({'height': maxH + 'px'});
    }

});
```

What it does is iterate through all of the container elements, measure them, and if the current element is higher than the previously highest element, it replaces the maxH variable. Once all containers have been reviewed, a function is fired to change all element heights to the highest.

This shouldn't affect your responsive as it doesn't care about width or how many units are in a row. A more sophisticated solution would only compare those in a single row, and you can check that by seeing how wide the parent element and how wide the containers are, then divide to determine in the current responsive layout how many columns are desired for each row and adjust from there.

I hope this helps give you some direction.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that most solution dealing with javascripts involved changes with heights. If you look at the dom on site, you will realize that under article we had another element named entry. I was trying to make article of equal height but after reviewing code I realized I could even make a child element of same height. I switched from article to entry and my problem resolved to certain extent. Then once in a while re-sizing I was again getting margin squishing problem. After some time realization came that my theme is using masonry plugin and may be that is causing problem/conflict. I removed masonry and site looks better. Still need to test fully on different devices and different scenarios to test if site works.

Want to take this opportunity to Thanks @practically for effort and help provided. His solution provided also will work but will provide highest height to all elements across rows. The plugin ( https://github.com/Sam152/Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows) works on rows wise height but is little slow to update the site and cause a bit of flicker.